# how to compare between two array that is inside one same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a code that produce this variable

```
let matches = [
 [1,3,5,8,10],
 [2,3,5,7,9],
 [1,2,3,5,9]
]
```

i wanted to find which of these value that appeared on all of these nested array. So in this example, the expected answer would be `[3,5]`

but i'm stumped on how should the algorithm work

Would be very grateful if someone can help me with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to solve this? Include your code and explain what's wrong with the results. Also, are the values in each sub-array unique within that sub-array?

Comment: We cannot help if you don't show us what you tried to solve it, even if it doesn't quite work fully.

Comment: Here's a candidate solution:

    let matches = [
     [1,3,5,8,10],
     [2,3,5,7,9],
     [1,2,3,5,9]
    ]
    
    let m1 = matches[0].slice();
    let mOther = matches.slice(1);
    let intersect = m1.filter((element) => mOther.every((other) => other.indexOf(element)>-1));
    
    document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(intersect) + "</pre>");


You can try it here https://jsfiddle.net/07ftsjLx/

Comment: @jarmod no, i'm looking for inspiration here. this should be a simple array compare that could be done with includes(). but the thing that confuses me is that the the array that i wanted to compare is inside the same array as the comparator.
so at the moment there is no result yet from my script.

the values in sub-array would be unique to that sub-array, yes.

Comment: @AllWorkNoPlay this works amazingly well! thank you!